# How to set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, directory, chmod

Is there a way to set chmod 755 for /project and all of its content including subfolders and files? Also, if I create a new folder or file, how can the chmod of that automatically be set to 755?

Actually I download a player form http://codecanyon.net/item/proradio-internet-radio-player/7990267?s_rank=1.1

While integrating this, the very first step is to provide chmod 0755 permissions to all player files and folders.

[documentation](https://prahec.com/project/proradio/docs) this is the link to the documentation.

please help. I know nothing so please bear with me.

Thanks again.

Comment: And this is tagged as `windows` why?

Comment: because I am working on windows. thanks

Comment: There is no native `chmod` in windows. You may want to lookup `attrib` and `icacls`.